# Generate a list from a vector in r

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a vector like `a`. I would like to generate a list `b` from `a`. I only typed the first 4 components of the list. Any suggestions of quick ways to achieve this be appreciated:

```
a <- seq(from =0, to = 359, by = 8) 
b <- list(c(0:7), c(8:(8+7)), c(16:(16+7)), c(24:(24+7)))

> b
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

[[3]]
[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23

[[4]]
[1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: @GregorThomas All should have 8 elements. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a sequence from `min` value of `a` to `max` and then use `findInterval` or `cut` to split the sequence based on intervals.

```
tmp <- seq(min(a), max(a))
split(tmp, findInterval(tmp, a))

#$`1`
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

#$`2`
#[1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

#$`3`
#[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23

#$`4`
#[1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

#$`5`
#[1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39

#...
```

---

Another way using `Map` :

```
Map(seq, a[-length(a)], a[-1] - 1)
```

Comment: It works fine. Could you explain a little bit about the `Map` method? such as how it picks up the interval of 8.  Thanks

Comment: It is dependent on your input `a` as you mentioned you have vector `a`. For first list it creates sequence between `a[1]` and `a[2] - 1`. For second it creates sequence between `a[2]` and `a[3] - 1` and so on for rest of the values.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This will achieve the desired result

```
list1 <- list()

for (i in 1:45) {
  base=i*8-8
  list1[[i]] <- base + 1:8
}
```